# Javascript equivalent of Python's dict.setdefault?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

In Python, for a dictionary `d`,

```
d.setdefault('key', value)
```

sets `d['key'] = value` if `'key'` was not in `d`, and otherwise leaves it as it is.

Is there a clean, idiomatic way to do this on a Javascript object, or does it require an `if` statement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's basically like using an `if` statement, but shorter:

```
d.key || (d.key = value);
```

Or

```
d.key = d.key || value;
```

Update: as @bobtato noted, if the property is already set to the value `false` it would overwrite it, so a better way would be:

```
!d.key && d.key !== false && (d.key = value);
```

Or, to do it as he suggested (just the shorthanded version):

```
'key' in d || (d.key = value);

// including overwriting null values:

('key' in d && d.key !== null) || (d.key = value);
```

Answer (score 26):

```
if (!('key' in d)) d.key = value;
```

or

```
'key' in d || (d.key = value);
```

(The last one uses [the short-circuit behavior of conditional expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930499/does-a-javascript-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions-test-all-of-them).)

---

"`d.key || (d.key = value)`" suggested in the other answer is buggy: if an element exists but evaluates to `false` ([`false`, `null`, `0`, `-0`, `""`, `undefined`, `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Description)), it will be silently overwritten.

- While this might be intended, it's most probably not intended for *all* of the aforementioned cases. So in such a case, check for the values separately:

  ```
  if (!('key' in d) || d.key === null) d.key = value;
  ```

Comment: I would say "Don't use it if the value is a boolean".

Comment: It's not just booleans though.  `d.key` evaluates as false if it is any of: `["", 0, false, NaN, null, undefined]`, **or** if it actually isn't defined, so the test can fail if d is being used to store strings, numbers, booleans or objects.  It's even possible to have a property which exists but holds the value `undefined` (because `d.key = undefined` is not the same as `delete d.key`).

Comment: But it also depends on the usage. If you're building a setDefault function, I agree. If you just need to set a property of some options that you passed to a function, you know what type it is and can use it in an adequate way.

Answer (score 26):

Nowadays you can also do `d.key ??= value`

Comment: amazing! thank you so much. May want to add a caveat that this works as long as entries are not allowed to legitimately by `undefined` or `null` (which should rarely be the case). And, as a bonus it is lazy, so an expression `??= expr` is not evaluated unnecessarily. I'm going to use this to replace python's `defaultdict` for when I only need to access a property in a single block of code e.g. `(keyToList[key] ??= []).push`.

Comment: For reference, this is called "Nullish coalescing assignment". More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing built-in, but this function will do it:

```
function setDefault(obj, prop, deflt) {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? obj[prop] : (obj[prop] = deflt);
}
```

If `obj` will only contain non-falsy values, `obj[prop] || (obj[prop] = deflt)` is a fine simple alternative (but `deflt` will override anything falsy). This has the added advantage that `deflt` will only get evaluated when its value is needed, so it's OK for it to be an expensive expression.

Answer (score 6):

It's not recommended and is never a good idea to augment the built-in classes.  Instead, it's better to create your own implementations of built-in classes, a lot like the YUI library does (YArray, etc).  However, I'm going to contradict that, because I often find that implementing useful short cuts like this are a benefit to writing clean maintainable code:

```
if (undefined === Object.prototype.setdefault) {
    Object.prototype.setdefault = function(key, def) {
        if (! this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this[key] = def;
        }
        return this[key];
    };
}
```

So let's see it in action...

```
var a = {};

a.setdefault('mylist', []).push(1);
a.setdefault('mylist', []).push(2);

console.log(a.mylist.toString());
    1,2
```

As has been pointed out, it's never a good idea to employ `thing = thing || defaultThing` because it only tests non-typed equality of `true`, or `thing == true`.  As opposed to typed equality: `thing === true` or `thing !== undefined`.  So the only way to properly code `setdefault` in an inline way would be to use this snippet everywhere:

```
/* null == thing is equivalent to... */
if (undefined !== thing && null !== thing) {
    thing = defaultThing;
}
/* ...but it's not explicit and linters don't like it! */
```

But as I already said, this just adds bloat to your code and is prone to errors acquired from "copy-and-paste" syndrome.

Comment: this should be the correct answer for this question

Comment: that said, adding setdefault method to EVERY object is debatable good practice

Answer (score 2):

```
a={}
key='3'
value = 2
a[key] = a[key] == undefined ? value : a[key]

## a = {'3': 2 }
```

Comment: A better test for undefined in Javascript is `typeof(a[key]) === "undefined"` and that will fail if you want to consider `null` values as empty which requires the additional test of `a[key] == null`. Since Javascript is a truthy language, both `undefined` and `null` are false and therefore a simple `a[key] || (a[key] = value)` is all that is necessary for this purpose and is quite common in practice.

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript** version of @DS. 's answer:

```js
export function setDefault<K extends string | number | symbol, T>(
  obj: Record<K, T>,
  prop: K,
  deflt: T,
) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? obj[prop] : (obj[prop] = deflt);
}
```

---

The line `// eslint-disable-next-line` aims to ignore the following eslint errors:

```
  9:3   error  Return statement should not contain assignment                             no-return-assign
  9:14  error  Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object  no-prototype-builtins
  9:50  error  Assignment to property of function parameter 'obj'                         no-param-reassign
```

If anyone knows how to improve the solution so that these errors are fixed instead of ignored, let me know.
I honestly don't see how it is possible to achieve this without assigning to the `obj` parameter.