# Why does `true ||1 === 1/3` returns true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I know that the `===` operator is used to determine whether its both operands are equal and identical or not. That is to say that if left side operand has 1 then the right side operand must be 1 for returning `true`. but I don't get why javascript returns true for this calculation.

```
true || 1 === 1/3;

//true;
```

I don't get how this result can be true in JavaScript.

Comment: Since the first part of your assertion is `true` and the operator is `OR` the second part is never evaluated. (With `OR` the first true operand is returned)

Comment: forgive me if u get this question boring for u. actually i'm very beggining js learner.

Comment: is the "true" and "1/3" are equal and identical?

Comment: Try this `alert(true || trash==good);` Nothing matters after that first `true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `===` Operation will never be checked. The statement is true by `true`.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930499/does-a-javascript-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions-test-all-of-them) question and answer on how if statements are evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

|| means or. 'True or false' always evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

`1 === 1/3` is `false`

`||` is `OR`

so your: `true || 1 === 1/3;` ->
`true` OR `false` is `true`

Answer (score 1):

> I know that === operator used to determine whether its both operands are equal and identical or not
>
> is the "true" and "1/3" are equal and identical?

From the question and comment it seems that you're mistakenly thinking that the expression means

```
(true || 1) === 1/3;
```

`true` and `1/3` are indeed **not** *equal and identical* so the expected result would be false. But it doesn't, since `||` has [lower precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `===`. So it's parsed like this: `true || (1 === 1/3);`.

Logical expressions in Javascript (and most other C-like languages) are [short-circuited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), hence after the result is determined, the remaining expressions won't evaluated. That means the final result would be true

Answer (score 0):

Your code boils down to this :

`true || 1 === 1/3 (false)`

or `true || false`

since the boolean operator `||` will return true if one of either conditions is true, you will end up with true.