# copyTo Not bringing correct data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am trying to run a script in Google Sheets. I have two sheets, one of which is a master list with all of my data and another of which is a sheet I am using to filter results when I want to look through a specific date/category. I'm doing this by having three cells in my filtering sheet that I would fill out information to match up with the master list and then having a button that would copy the data over. Here is my code:

```
function filter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Total");
  var month = ss.getSheetByName("Filter").getRange("A2").getValue();
  var payment = ss.getSheetByName("Filter").getRange("B2").getValue();
  var category = ss.getSheetByName("Filter").getRange("C2").getValue();


  for(var i = 1; i < 200; i++)
  {
  var p = s.getRange(i, 5);
  var c = s.getRange(i, 6);  
  var m = s.getRange(i, 7);

   if( p.getValue() == payment && c.getValue() == category && m.getValue() 
== month){
     var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Filter");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(i, 1, 1, 7).copyTo(target);
   }


  }
}
```

Using `&&` conditional inside of my if statement results in nothing appearing. Using `||` conditional results in everything appearing. I can't seem to figure out how to make it so that I can sort by just one category OR all categories.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have some sample data that it should work on?

Comment: Here is a spreadsheet using the same code with some sample data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VRY1P5drqiHaARZM5xvutt6K0TvE0drZ8d5_AycMncg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Aloy I used your code above and cannot reproduce the issue in my copy of the sample sheet. Are there specific steps or combinations that reliably reproduce the bug?

Comment: @BrianBennett an example would be if you try to filter by "September" and "Cash." This will bring in everything from September and everything from cash, but I am trying to get it to bring in only rows with both of those values. However, if I change the script from using '| |' to using '&&' then it brings in none of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need all 3 values using a short-circuit comparitor (`&&` and `||`). If the condition isn't met, the script exits. You also need to clean up your logic tests by grouping items in parentheses.

For instance,

```
if(p.getValue() == payment && m.getValue() == month)
```

returns values with "September" *and* "Cash" only. "Category" is irrelevant.

Using

```
if((p.getValue() == payment && m.getValue() == month) || (p.getValue() == payment && c.getValue() == category))
```

will return a row if the payment *and* the value match *or* if payment *and* category match, regardless of month.

Breaking conditions out using parentheses will help. Also, reconsider using comparators that short circuit a script. [This post describing the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930499/does-a-javascript-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions-test-all-of-them) may help.