# logical OR in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, logical-operators

How to make a condition with logical OR in SQL (MySQL), so that the sub-conditions would be carried out on an as-needed basis ?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM \`mytable\` WHERE (\`a\` || \`b\` || \`c\`)
```

> `a` is FALSE
>   `b` is TRUE
>   `c` is FALSE or TRUE

I want to MySQL:

1) get `a`                                 // ok, `a` is FALSE 
2) if (`a` IS TRUE) break        // no break 
3) get `b`                               // ok, `b` is TRUE 
4) if (`b` IS TRUE) break;        // ok, break

Comment: Looking at the last part of your question, are you asking whether the expression `a OR b OR c` [short-circuits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960767/do-modern-dbms-include-short-circuit-boolean-evaluation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical `OR` already behaves that way.

However what is considered evaluation of those expressions is not necessarily what you expect, e.g. database may still need to fetch all rows related to the expression. Specifically, [MySQL can't always use indexes if you use `OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

BTW: You should use `OR`, which is a standard SQL syntax. `||` in ANSI SQL (other databases and ANSI mode in MySQL) concatenates strings.

Answer (score 0):

If they are boolean fields Try using this

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `a` OR `b` OR `c`
```

Comment: my `c` is sub-query (SELECT * FROM `mytable2` WHERE ... LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, you just have to reorder your operands. As soon, as an operand of OR is TRUE, the condition is not further evaluated. To achieve high performance, you must put the operands that are most likely true in front of the others.

You don't want a break, if `a` is TRUE? Try this for a start:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `c` OR `b` OR `a`
```