# c++ logical expression optimization

Tags: javascript, c++, c, optimization

Is it okay for me to presume in C or C++ or JavaScript or any other modern language that if I do…

```
bool funt1(void) {…}
bool funt2(void) {…}
if (funt1() && funt2()) {Some code}
```

… Am I guaranteed that both functions get called or if `funt1` returns false can the compiler bail on me and never call `funt2`?

Comment: in most languages - if funt1 returns false, second will NOT be called

Comment: [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: Why no short-circuit in C++ for overloaded operators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913237/is-there-actually-a-reason-why-overloaded-and-dont-short-circuit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232603/do-all-programming-languages-have-boolean-short-circuit-evaluation

wiki suggests it's up to the compiler as to whether or not it short circuits for fortran.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification. I consider my question answered. Do I close the question or does the moderator? I'm not really familiar with all the details of how this site works.

Answer (score 4):

In C, C++, and Javascript, the logical operators `&&` and `||` short circuit, i.e. in `A && B`, `A` is evaluated first and `B` evaluated if and only if `A` returned `true`. Similarly, in `A || B`, `B` is evaluated if and only if `A` returned false. These are guaranteed by the language standards and apply even if `B` has side effects (in fact, this can be used to control those side effects).

In C++, these rules only apply to the logical operators applied to built in types, but not to user-defined logical operators of the same name. However, in your code snippet, two `bool` are compared, so this cannot be a user-defined `&&`.

Comment: Now we just need an example of a "modern" language where short-circuiting is not used...

Comment: @Deduplicator According to the Wikipedia site linked in quantdev's comment, [MUMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS) does not have short circuit, but I don't know nothing about this illness (including whether it supports operators `AND` and/or `OR`). However, pretty much any computer language has short circuit evaluation on these two operators.

Comment: The only thing I know about it (hearsay) validates that characterization. But here's a tip: C++ operator overloading.

Comment: @Deduplicator Okay, user-defined `operator&&` and `operator||` (on other than two built-in types) will not use short circuit evaluation. But that is not really in the realm of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pitfall in C++: If the first and the second function return objects and both are needed for the logical operation, there is no short circuit.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};

bool operator || (const A&, const B&) { return true; }

A a() { std::cout << "A\n"; return A(); }
B b() { std::cout << "B\n"; return B(); }

bool f() { std::cout << "f\n"; return true; }
bool g() { std::cout << "g\n"; return true; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(a() || b());
    if(f() || g());
}
```

Comment: Actually, when the operator is overloaded. One of them not having any impact on the final result does not change anything. Shameless plug of a question I answered about the feasability of allowing overloaded operators to short-circuit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25913422

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Am I guaranteed that both functions get called or if `funt1` returns `false` can the compiler bail on me and never call `funt2`?

If `funt1()` returns `false`, it is guaranteed that `funt2()` will never get called.

If `funt1()` returns `true`, it is guaranteed that `funt2()` will get called.